# How to popup success message in odoo?

Tags: python, popup, odoo, message

I am sending invitation by clicking button after clicking button and successfully sending invitation there is pop up message of successfully invitation send. But the problem is that the main heading of pop up message is *Odoo Server Error*. That is because I am using

```
raise osv.except_osv("Success", "Invitation is successfully sent")
```

Is there any alternative to make it better.

Comment: @adamStrauss could you explain why did you accept my answer then you removed it? Is the answer wrong or you want a fancy way to do it?

Comment: @CharifDZ sorry for that. It was my mistake, your answer is right. It was done by my daughter a little naughty creature. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I need something like this I have a dummy `wizard` with `message` field, and have a simple form view that show the value of that field.

When ever I want to show a message after clicking on a button I do this:

```py
     @api.multi
     def action_of_button(self):
        # do what ever login like in your case send an invitation
        ...
        ...
        # don't forget to add translation support to your message _()
        message_id = self.env['message.wizard'].create({'message': _("Invitation is successfully sent")})
        return {
            'name': _('Successfull'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'message.wizard',
            # pass the id
            'res_id': message_id.id,
            'target': 'new'
        }
```

The `form  view` of message wizard is as simple as this:

```xml
<record id="message_wizard_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">message.wizard.form</field>
    <field name="model">message.wizard</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form >
            <p class="text-center">
                <field name="message"/>
            </p>
        <footer>
            <button name="action_ok" string="Ok" type="object" default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/> 
        </footer>
        <form>
    </field>
</record>
```

`Wizard` is just simple is this:

```py
class MessageWizard(model.TransientModel):
    _name = 'message.wizard'

    message = fields.Text('Message', required=True)

    @api.multi
    def action_ok(self):
        """ close wizard"""
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

**Note:**  Never use `exceptions` to show **Info message** because everything run inside a big `transaction` when you click on button and if
there is any `exception` **raised** a Odoo will do `rollback` in the `database`, and you will lose your data if you don't `commit` your job first manually before that, witch is not **recommended** too in Odoo

Comment: This solution didn't work if we use in `ir.actions.server` in odoo 15

Comment: This solution work very well in Odoo 14 :)

Answer (score 4):

If previous answer is not working, try this:

In odoo 15 version, you can use this:

```
# show success message
title = _("Successfully!")
message = _("Your Action Run Successfully!")
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'display_notification',
    'params': {
        'title': title,
        'message': message,
        'sticky': False,
    }
}
```

Note:

Remember to add this line in your python file to translate the message:

```
from odoo import _
```

Also, you will need to add `action = ...` in xml file or else it won't work:

```
<field name="code">action = model.your_function()</field>
```

Example xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_your_action_name" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Your Action</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model_name"/>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="mymodule.model_your_model_name"/>
        <!-- set this action is appear in form or list -->
        <field name="binding_view_types">list</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <!-- function called -->
        <field name="code">action = model.your_function()</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

i'm not sure why, but if we remove the `action = ...` part, so it look like this, it won't work:

```
<field name="code">model.your_function()</field>
```

Hope it's help, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a button and the text is static, you can also use a button confirm attribute in xml,ex.

```
 <button string="Change Next Activity Date" name="change_next_activity_date"
                                type="object" class="btn-primary" confirm="are you sure you want to change the Date?"/>
```

It will display a confirmation dialog with yes and Cancel button on it and won't break the process. Same as Yes or no option.