# could any one say how to show custom dialog box to print account verified successfully in odoo or python?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to display a **`successful message`** in Odoo but unable to do so when I try using Odoo existing functionality it is displaying as a **`Error Message`**

> My Message: Account Verified

Tried:

```
raise UserError('Account Verified')
```

Comment: Please read [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to get better in asking. This question for example is just too less information. What are you doing with an account: editing, calling an action/method, creating? Why is the `UserError` not fulfilling your requirment? Just some example questions to your question. Always try to answer them to yourself. If you got the information and are left without a solution, ask StackOverflow. And please stop using "//" in the beginning of sentences. That's no normal use in english, and StackOverflow is english only.

Comment: Yes you can create this by using wizard. One day I was searching for the same solution so someone on stackoverflow helped me I'm sharing the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302569/how-to-popup-success-message-in-odoo

Comment: Thanks , i'm new to using this. @CZoellner

Comment: @Saks_here yes i know, that's why i was writing it ;-)